How can I make a SUMPRODUCT formula use only the values marked with a checkbox?
I have a list of colors in column C.
List of colors and combinations
Since I need to know how many times a word is mentioned in column C, I use this formula that I found in the internet
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(MockData1!C:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MockData1!C:C,A2,"")))/LEN(A2))

Quantity of colors in MockData1 sheet, column C
This is the LINK to the Google sheet with editor rights.
I would like to know how to adapt that formula (or, there may be another formula) so it only sums up the quantity of colors mentioned in a checked box row. Thank you in advance for your help.
I'm self-learning a bit of code and formulas but I usually copypaste what I need. I don't know how to adapt complex formulas, I tried with AND, and IF but it didn't work, I couldn't write the formula correctly.
Edit: Tedinoz has answered my question in the comments, with the exact formula I needed for my purposes. Thank you so much, Tedinoz, for your kind help.
=QUERY({flatten(arrayformula(trim(split(query({MockData1!A2:C},"select Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col1 =true"),","))))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''") 


What environment is that, Excel?

It's Google Sheets, I could share the direct link to edit... I'm gonna go ahead and do that... I should have done that before :'D

Regarding "How to add a COUNTIF within an ARRAYFORMULA using wildcards/partial match" look at the solution by @JPV. In your case, this might translate to something like: =QUERY({flatten(arrayformula(trim(split(query({MockData1!A2:C},"select Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col1 =true"),","))))},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''")

Thank you again, Tedinoz, I added the suggestion, however it was your formula that answered my specific question, because yeah, that's what I wanted, and I don't know how much time I would have take adapting formulas from the other question... What is the procedure now? My question then is closed? I wonder if you could answer with your formula and I'll give it a green check.
Oh, I might edit my question adding your formula there too

Hi. The question is closed as a "duplicate", so it won't be opened. And yes, it often takes time to interpret and adapt another answer to one's own scenario. I'm pleased that you've got a solution. Consider it as paying forward; you might be in a similar situation one day where you can help someone else.
